# Discount Function in NDCG

Tags: ranking, information-retrieval

While in Normalised Discounted Cumulative Gain (NDCG) it is common to use 1/log2(1+rank) as a discount function, is there any studies that use a different discount function for different application other than information retrieval that does not focus only on the top results?